# RxJS and Typescript catch error with the same type

Tags: typescript, error-handling, rxjs

I use RxJS and I need to return an observable of that type im my method: `Observable<MyStuff>`

When I want to throw an error I use:

```
import { throwError } from "rxjs";
/// ... stuff
return throwError('Error stuff invalid');
```

`throwError` return an `Observable<never>` and it's not the same type as `Observable<MyStuff>`

I want to throw an error with that type: `Observable<MyStuff>`
I don't want to change the return type of my function if it's possible

What is the best practice to handle error with observables ?

Comment: Where you have an Observable with type `Observable<MyStuff>`?

Comment: This is my return type

Comment: When everything goes well I return that type

Comment: Can you show the whole chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw an error without necessarily using ThrowError from rxjs , you can do it in this way , you replace 
return ThrowError("Your error");
with 
throw "Error";

and simply catch it when subscribing to your observable like follow
YourrReturnedObservable.subscribe(successData => {Your code logic } , err => { // catch exceptions here} );

Comment: Just perfect, yeah so now I think when you are on a pipe you have to just throw and It will go to the error handling